# Update text file method

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a jtable that can be edite and then saved (updated) to a text file.
User select a line (that contains a book record) and request to borrow that book,
I use this method to update, But now when update, the old data is not deleted.

```
user_AllBooks uAllBooks = new user_AllBooks();
    @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == borrowButton) {
        borrowInitialize(bTable.getSelectedRow());
}

    public void borrowInitialize(int row) {
    if (uAllBooks.getValueAt(row, 3).equals("Yes")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This Book Was Borrowed");
    } else {
        uAllBooks.setValueAt("Yes", row, 3);
        uAllBooks.fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row);
        uAllBooks.updateFiles(uAllBooks.bData);
    }
}
...
}

public class user_AllBooks extends AbstractTableModel {
...

public void updateFiles(ArrayList<BookInformation> data) {
    PrintWriter Bpw = null;
    try {
        Bpw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("AllBookRecords.txt" , true));
        for (BookInformation bookinfo : data) {
            String line = bookinfo.getBookID()
                    + "     " + bookinfo.getBookName()
                    + "     " + bookinfo.getBookDate()
                    + "     " + bookinfo.getBorrowStatus();
            Bpw.println(line);
        }

        Bpw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    }
}
...
}
```

My BookInformation Class:

```
public class BookInformation {

private String BookName;
private String BookDate;
private String BookID;
private String BorrowStatus;

public String getBookName() {
    return BookName;
}

public void setBookName(String book_name) {
    this.BookName = book_name;
}

public String getBookDate() {
    return BookDate;
}

public void setBookDate(String book_date) {
    this.BookDate = book_date;
}

public String getBookID() {
    return BookID;
}

public void setBookID(String Book_id) {
    this.BookID = Book_id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return BookID + "     " + BookName + "     "
            + BookDate + "     " + BorrowStatus + "\n";
}

public String getBorrowStatus() {
    return BorrowStatus;
}

public void setBorrowStatus(String borrowStat) {
    BorrowStatus = borrowStat;
}
}
```

Thanks.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like you have windows 7. For better screenshots in the future, type in "snipping tool" in the start menu and use that.

Comment: See also [*How do I create screenshots?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
Bpw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("AllBookRecords.txt" , true));
```

to

```
Bpw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("AllBookRecords.txt" , false));
```

The second parameter (boolean) changes whether it should append the text file (add to the end of it) or just rewrite everything.

Source: [Javadoc constructor summary for FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html):

```
FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append) 
    Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean
    indicating whether or not to append the data written.
```